# Web Role on Windows Azure and iisreset side effects

Tags: azure, instance, reset, webrole, iisreset

I noticed that when you RDP to a Web Role instance on Windows Azure to make an `iisreset`, the `World Wide Web Publishing Service` shuts down, and the only way to get your role up and running again is either by restarting the aforementioned service or re-roll/restart your instance.

For reasons unknown to me, Windows Azure default the start mode of `World Wide Web Publishing Service` to `Manual`, why an `iisreset` sort a leave your Web Role unavailable to the WWW.

I found a solution to this - IMO - odd behavior, and answered it to the original question of this post.

However, is there an alternative to `iisreset` on Windows Azure - maybe programmatically where I can pinpoint the exact instance? Because that is another issue; now I have to use RDP to each instance .. it would be nice if it was possible to do a pinpoint each instance.

Think about it; i have a CNAME to www.awesome-azure.com; this is hosted by 3 instances in round-robin, and I want to reset/monitor/diagnose/heartbeat each one through a REST API (ir similiar), and not like now - through RDP.

Can this be achieved.

**EDIT**

Tried to make it more clear what the challenge is as well as the goal to achieve.

**EDIT 2**

Provided a solution to the `iisreset` challenge; updated the question to pinpoint instances over the Internet if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I still don't know why Microsoft Azure decides to set `World Wide Web Publishing Service` to start mode `Manual`, but I found a way to change it.

To the second part of the original question I still hoping for an answer, but until then, please find my solution for the first part to fix the (IMO) `iisreset` problem with Startup Task:

In your **startup.cmd** (or what ever you have named it) which I have placed in a **startup** folder in the root of my application, include this line of text:

**powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted .\startup\w3svc.ps1**

In the same folder, create a PowerShell file named w3svc.ps1 with the following content:

**Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W3SVC -Name Start -Value 2**

Voila; your IIS now works as expected - `World Wide Web Publishing Service` is now set to start mode `Automatically`.

Note: for the above to work, you need to have your **osFamily** property set to **2** in you  **ServiceConfiguration.cscfg** file.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the [RoleEnvironment.Changing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.changing.aspx) event in WebRole.cs and set the Cancel property on the event arguments object to true. Then you just need to make a change to the configuration settings and Azure will restart all your instances in an orderly fashion.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying - sorry for that. Let's say I have 3 instances in a round-robin configuration. Say I want to make an iisreset (or alternate way) one-by-one/specific but without using RDP. Can this be achieved - and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why `iisreset` isn't working. As to your second question, you can use the Service Management API to reboot or reimage an instance. That might do what you want. You could also, of course, write your own code to do whatever you want. (You could have code in your web role that polls a blob called `<instance ID>.txt` and does an `iisreset` any time the blob changes.)

Comment: Well, iisreset is working, but i leaves the World Wide Web Publishing Service offline. Reboot or reimage is to slow. I will have a look into the API you sugested .. I was just so naive to believe there was an easier way; i mean - others must have the need (like SiteScope) to monitor uptime or similiar.

Comment: Selectively calling something (like `iisreset`) on a single instance is kind of antithetical to the way Windows Azure works. I'm not sure why you're doing it, in fact. Your instances are stateless, right? So why would you need to do something on a specific instance?

Comment: I don't know about you - but do to time-to-market and other factors, sometimes you stage a version that is not as stable as you wish for.  This could in-mem caching or if an unhandled exception is thrown the Web Role's IIS might suffer a sudden death. From here it's much easier to simply make an iisreset. Windows Azure works just like any other hosting company, so I do not tend to agree on the antithetical part - especially not with the opening of own virtual machines (where one could argue that you have "full" control).